# Is it possible to change the individual lengths of the arcs within a D3 Sunburst Diagram?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been working on a requirement for one of my projects using D3. The requirement is that to have the arcs (more specifically the last ring of arcs) to have different lengths based on whether it was performing optimally or not. ie: if the arc was skinny and long it was performing not up to scratch, whereas if the arc was thick and short it was performing optimally.

Just wondering if this was possible with D3, as all the examples I've seen have the same length arcs from this example I've been following: https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-sunburst

I think it does stem from the below code when I set up the
angles for the arcs.

```
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
    .clamp(true);

const y = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .range([maxRadius * 0.07, maxRadius]);

const arc = d3.arc()
    .startAngle(d => x(d.x0))
    .endAngle(d => x(d.x1))
    .innerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y0)))
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .outerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y1)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, for anyone else who is curious how to do this.

```
    .innerRadius(function (d) {
        if (d.data.size == 144) {
            return Math.max(0, y(1))
        } else {
            return Math.max(0, y(d.y0))
        }
    })
    .outerRadius(function (d) {
        if (d.data.size == 144) {
            return Math.max(0, y(0.373))
        } else {
            return Math.max(0, y(d.y1))
        }
```

What I've done is specified that for the arc with the value of 144 will have the start and end position of the arc length changed. I'll attach a picture as well to show the end result:

[D3 Sunburst Chart Arc Length Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoI9Z.png)